# Plotly Parallel coordinate plot: change order of axes

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I would like to change the order of the axes in a parallel coordinate plot using plotly.
Here is the parallel coordinate plot for the Iris data:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color="species_id", 
                              color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose,
                              color_continuous_midpoint=2)
fig.show()
```

I have tried adding labels and reordering them, but that didn't work. I don't see anything in the  [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.parallel_coordinates.html) that lets me reorder the axis. Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: Solved now. The problem was that I had specified dimensions as a set with curly brackets:

```
dimensions={"petal_length","sepal_width"}
```

The order can be specified using a list with square brackets:

```
 dimensions=["petal_length","sepal_width"]
```